# getting maximum number from many-to-many relation (not properly ended)

Tags: oracle

i have 2 tables with many-to-many relation

```
book
-----
|ID |
-----
 1  
 2 
 3  


book_category
-----------------------
|book_id|category_id |
-----------------------
 1       |1
 2       |1
 3       |2


category
----------
|id|name |
----------
 1 |1
 2 |1
 3 |2
```

i need to show the name of the most common category 
i'm trying this query

```
     select name,num from category inner join 
     (select category_id, count(book_id) as num from book_category group by 
      category_id) on id = category_id
        where num >= all (select count(book_id) from book_category group by 
        category_id) on id = category_id)
```

and getting sql command not properly ended.
tried many different thing still not working, any help is appreciated. 
thanks ^_^

Comment: What is your DB? Oracle or mysql

Comment: Don't tag your question with databases you aren't using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from inner query toward outer ones, we take `count(book_id)` for all `category_id`, rank them in descending order and then filter the entry/entries based on the rank = 1 condition. Even if there are more than one `category_id`  with same highest `count(book_id)`, you will see all of them in the result.

```
SELECT B.CATEGORY_ID, B.NUM
FROM
    (
    SELECT A.CATEGORY_ID, A.NUM, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.NUM DESC) AS MOST_COMMON_RANK
    FROM
        (SELECT CATEGORY_ID, COUNT(BOOK_ID) AS NUM 
         FROM BOOK_CATEGORY 
         GROUP BY CATEGORY_ID ORDER BY COUNT(BOOK_ID) DESC) A
    ) B
WHERE B.MOST_COMMON_RANK = 1;
```

Comment: it worked, one more question if i want the least common i can just replace (ORDER BY A.NUM DESC) to (ORDER BY A.NUM ) because the defualt is Ascending. thanks so much

Comment: Yup, for least common you can remove the `DESC` keyword. Welcome!

Comment: Yup, for least common you can remove the `DESC` keyword. Welcome!